# Control arrangement on MFC Dlg box

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, space

how can I arrange the spaces between controls on MFC dialog box?

[image]

the space between static box(RX Data) and large Edit box may be not equal to space between "size of RX Data" and the above mentioned Edit box.

Comment: You have to do this by hand. AFAIK there is no way to do this automatically with the dialog editor. You have to find out the y distance ftom "RX Data" to the first edit box, and then place manually the second edit box that same y distance lower than "size of RX Data". The position of the selected item is displayed in Vusial Studio's status bar.

Comment: add a tag of which visual studio version you are using please

Answer (score 2):

you can use two ways to achiev this, there might be more.

## Changing the RC file manually

1. open the solution explorer
2. look for your "*.rc" file
3. right click it and select "View Code"
4. search for your dialog resource using your dialog ID, it should look something like this

   ```
   IDD_DIALOG2 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 316, 182
   STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
   CAPTION "Dialog"
   FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
   BEGIN
       DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,205,161,50,14
       PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,259,161,50,14
       LTEXT           "RX Data",IDC_STATIC,23,26,27,8
       EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,23,38,148,65,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
       LTEXT           "size of RX Data",IDC_STATIC,23,119,50,8
       EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT2,23,131,40,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
   END
   ```
5. there you can see all the controls you have created, and you can notice a sequence of 4 numbers separated by a comma i.e.:23,26,27,8
6. 23,26,27,8 are the coordinates in the dialog of the control

   1. 23 is the distance from the left of the dialog
   2. 26 is the distance from the top of the dialog
   3. 27 is the width
   4. 9 is the height
7. so just adjust the coordinates as you wish and you will get the exact position you want
8. done

## Using dialog editor (I don't like this one)

1. select all your four controls
2. right click
3. select align left
4. select just the bottom two
5. move them to the right of the first two
6. select only the labels, right click, align tops
7. select only the edit controls, right click, align tops
8. select the two controls that were on the right and move them back to the bottom
9. done

Answer (score 2):

You can NOT do a precise control alignment in your rc file, neither with the UI tools nor manually. The reason is: resource file expresses all points in dialog units, that will be converted to pixel at run time depending on DPI settings, subject to rounding errors.

You can adjust position of your controls at run time in OnInitDialog() with single-pixel precision.